# Sails.js - Many-to-Many fails to save

Tags: mongodb, express, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I have a simple need to add tags to patients. I followed the Sails and Waterline documentation concerning many-to-many associations, but it's failing at some point (no errors). I'm using MongoDB for data storage. Code below:

Tag Model

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
  name: 'STRING',
  color: {
      type: 'STRING',
      defaultsTo: '#777777'
  },
  tagged: {
      collection: 'patient',
      via: 'tags',
      dominant: true
  }

}
};
```

Patient Model

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    name: 'STRING',
    tags: {
        collection: 'tag',
        via: 'tagged'
    }
}
};
```

And this is the controller method that tries to associate data:

```
module.exports = {

addToPatient: function(req, res) {
    Patient.findOne({id: req.param('patientId')}).exec(function(err, patient) {

        // Queue up a record to be inserted into the join table
        patient.tags.add(req.param('tagId'));

        // Save the user, creating the new associations in the join table
        patient.save(function(err) {});
    });

    res.send("tag assigned");
}
};
```

I've inspected the responses at various breaks and everything seems to be passing just fine. The patient is found. The save function shows a tag association in the patient object, but nothing is added in the database. I assume I will see either a join table being created or something in the patient/tag collections to signify an association, but I see nothing. I'm so very confused. If I do an HTTP get, I'm presented with a "tag assigned" response. What am I missing?

Comment: Works fine for me on Mongo with your exact code, and creates a `patient_tags__tag_tagged` collection.  You should move the `res.send` inside the callback for `patient.save`, though--right now it will always say "tag assigned" even if there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, but you're right in the **tag** and **patient** collections, you won't see a populated field with the associations. You'll see new join collections that are created that contains the relationships like @sgress454 pointed out.